# How to display window number in my mode-line?

Tags: mode-line, mode-line-format

I use [window-numbering package](https://github.com/nschum/window-numbering.el) to switch between windows in emacs, however I am struggling to display window number in my mode-line, preferably in [#] format (i.e. [[1](https://github.com/nschum/window-numbering.el)], [[2](https://github.com/deb0ch/emacs-winum)],   [3] ...).

What variable can I use to append window number to my mode-line-format list? Please see below an example of my configuration.

```
(setq-default mode-line-format (list
    " "
    '(:eval (if (vc-backend buffer-file-name)
                (list
                 (propertize octicon-octoface 'face 'octicons-modeline)
                 (propertize " "              'face 'mode-line))))
   mode-line-mule-info
   'mode-line-modified
   "-  "
   'mode-line-buffer-identification
   "  (%l, %c)  "
   'mode-line-modes
   " -- "
   `(vc-mode vc-mode)
))
```

PS I've also tried a much newer [winum package](https://github.com/deb0ch/emacs-winum), with the same results...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try this (have not tested, because I don't installed
`window-numbering`, it found it in source code https://github.com/nschum/window-numbering.el/blob/master/window-numbering.el#L228.)

```el
(setq-default mode-line-format (list
                                " "
                                '(:eval (window-parameter (selected-window) 'ace-window-path))
                                '(:eval (if (vc-backend buffer-file-name)
                                            (list
                                             (propertize octicon-octoface 'face 'octicons-modeline)
                                             (propertize " "              'face 'mode-line))))
                                mode-line-mule-info
                                'mode-line-modified
                                "-  "
                                'mode-line-buffer-identification
                                "  (%l, %c)  "
                                'mode-line-modes
                                " -- "
                                `(vc-mode vc-mode)
                                ))
```

Comment: thanks for your response. I had switched to ace-window and tried adding `(:eval (window-parameter (selected-window) 'ace-window-path))` to my modeline list, however this doesn't seem to have done anything. How would you add it to the config example that I have above?

Comment: Did you add `'` before `(:eval (window-parameter (selected-window) 'ace-window-path))`.

Comment: I updated answer, and tested on my Emacs, it works fine.